# Ruby Garbage Collection Heap Slot size

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

So, ruby enterprise documentation states that all the values in the GC settings are defined in slots: http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/documentation.html#_garbage_collector_performance_tuning

(e.g. RUBY_HEAP_MIN_SLOTS)

We fine-tuned our app's min slot size and increment for the best performance by trial and error (we have enough machines to get a good idea how different values affect the number of malloc calls and Full GCs).

But something has been bugging me for a while: How big is 1 slot in bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p136
$ gdb ruby
(gdb) p sizeof(RVALUE)
$1 = 40
```

Comment: What is gdb? What does `$1 =` mean in this context? What units is "40" in?

Comment: `p` = `print`; `$1` is the return value; `40` is the size in bytes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof

Answer (score 4):

From Ruby source:

```
 *  sizeof(RVALUE) is
 *  20 if 32-bit, double is 4-byte aligned
 *  24 if 32-bit, double is 8-byte aligned
 *  40 if 64-bit
```

Answer (score 1):

The default in 1.9 is 8K

http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/trunk/gc.c
(search for HEAP_SIZE)

Note well that whenever it runs out of space and needs to reallocate, in 1.9 it allocates exponentially more heaps.

In 1.8 it would allocate bigger and bigger heaps.

Comment: The question is about the size of 1 slot (i.e. the default min heap size is 10_000 slots, how big is 1 slot)

Answer (score 1):

After diggin' through the code:

`1 slot` is a size of `sizeof(struct RVALUE)`, which depends on the machine.